# Karate Mobile test framework throwing error when do click option

Tags: mobile, automation, appium, karate

I

**Feature file**

```
Scenario: Validate My Contacts page
    Given driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(android.desiredConfig)"} }
    Then click("//*[@text='My Contacts']")
    ...
    ...
```

**Exception**

```
{message=An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters (id='%5B%5D')}
```

**Troubleshooting finds**

1. `click()` function calls elementFind api and returns `HTTP 200`
2. Then it calls `elementClick` api with the elementID, which returns `HTTP 500`
3. Noticed that `elementClick` api doesn't have valid `elementID`.

**Tech stack**

Appium Studio v21
Karate 1.0.0 (issue exists in 0.9.6)

Kindly share your guidance points to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how `appium studio` works with karate, but it is recommended to use `appium` installed via `npm`. Also, make sure you have the latest version of Appium or at least a version above 1.9 (where they seem to start supporting w3c spec)

Also try upgrading your karate version to `1.1.0.RC1`,

If you are still facing issue, please follow https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue and help us to reproduce.

Comment: I used delay also. I did debug inside karate-core.jar v1.0.0 and find that each method first find the element in doc and do the action. In my case, element found successfully and that element id isn't pass to action apis like call, input etc.  kindly help me on this